# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named healthcenters

Tags: mysql, scala, jpa

I'm trying to connect my scala code to mysql using JPA, and I keep going in circles coming back to this error:

```
scala> DataToStore.storeData(url)
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named healthcenters
  at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:89)
  at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
  at healthcenterdataload.Model$.emf(Model.scala:11)
  at healthcenterdataload.Model$.em(Model.scala:13)
  at healthcenterdataload.DataToStore$.storeData(HealthCenter.scala:41)
  ... 38 elided
```

Here's my persistence.xml, which is in src/META-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="healthcenters">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>healthcenterdataload.DataToStoreClass</class>
        <class>healthcenterdataload.HealthCenterData</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/healthcenters"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And here are my dependencies in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.5.1",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.5.1",
  "javax.persistence" % "persistence-api" % "1.0",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "5.2.10.Final",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "5.2.10.Final"
```

My database name and persistence unit currently have the same name, but changing that doesn't seem to help anything.

Thoughts? This is my first time getting a project wired together like this, so it's a learning process! :)

Thanks!

Comment: either the provider is not present in the classpath, or you have specified the provider incorrectly

Comment: Thanks! turns out my META-INF folder needed to go under src/main/resources. Now it's finding other errors, which I'll go hunting to solve... :)